# How to change object index manually on insert new object

Tags: c#, .net, arraylist

How can user add some objects on **specific indexes** manually and **shift others**.

My Code:

```
List<Temp> TempLST = new List<Temp>(){};

Temp T1=new Temp(){P1=a1,P2=b1};
TempLST.Add(T1);

Temp T2=new Temp(){P1=a2,P2=b2};
TempLST.Add(T2);

Temp T3=new Temp(){P1=a3,P2=b3};
TempLST.Add(T3);
```

For Example: Now I want to add new object between second and third item of TempLST

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
    TempLST.Insert(2, new Temp(){P1=a4,P2=b4});
```

index arg is zero based, so, the third element is 2 (position after second element)